# Error "Please enter a correct entity model." while Importing CSV in custom module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I receive this error when i'm trying to import a list of `sellers` (custom module). I want to know what is the meaning of this error? and where should I start to fix the problem?
[image: X Please enter a correct entity model.]

**PS**: Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Have you got solution how to import categories using csv ? I have facing same issue. Let me know if you have got solution?

Answer (score 2):

In my, case i had parent::__consturct() in my __construc() method. Then the parent class is an abstract class. I think there is the error.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config,
    ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
)
{
    parent::__construct($jsonHelper, $importExportData, $importData, $config, $resource, $resourceHelper, $string, $errorAggregator);
}
```

Without parent::__construct() the error message disappear.

Answer (score 1):

a) Simply solution to reset the folder permission due to `export/import` file will be save in `var/export` or `var/import` folder.

```
chmod -R 0777 var/
```

b) Check the exception.log file in `var/log`

Comment: that's the b) that worked for me, for a), I'd advise to just reset magento permissions but 777 is not recommended, right?